# Can we integrate the Google Data Studio dashboard into our website as a home view?

Tags: google-analytics, looker-studio

I have the google data studio reporting dashboard of my laravel website and I want to integrate this dashboard as a home page of my site’s admin panel when I hit the page. Is it possible to integrate this dashboard in my website so that every time I open my admin panel it shows me the same view of data studio as a dashboard first? Meanwhile, instead of writing a code to develop dashboard, I want to show the exact same view of data studio on my site.

Answer (score 0):

It's not recommended, but there is a workaround.

**First**, you need to make your data studio report open to world wide. That means click on share --> advanced --> Select -- On- Public on the web .

[image]

**Secondly**, add that report inside an iframe on the web page, and your problem would be resolved ;)